# Beginner java What is the error and why?

Tags: java, swing

```
JTextField ageTxt;
ageTxt = new JTextField("30");
int age = ageTxt.getText( );

if (age < 30)
    System.out.println("You are young");
else
    System.out.println("You are NOT young");
```

Comment: The code does not compile, so your compiler will give you an error message, which should be fairly self explanatory, including a line number pointing to the line on which the error occurs (something like: can't assign String to int for example).

Comment: Do you want us to guees the error?

Comment: If you don't understand the error message from the compiler, then post the compilation error message, here.

Comment: Please provide a proper description of you problem.

Answer (score 5):

`ageTxt.getText()` returns a `java.lang.String`. You are trying to assign that to an primitive `int` That will not work.

You can use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert a `String` to an `int`. But note that this might throw a `NumberFormatException` when the string is not a valid number. So you might want to wrap it in a `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextField ageTxt;
ageTxt = new JTextField("30");
String age = ageTxt.getText( );

if (Integer.parseInt(age) < 30)
    System.out.println("You are young");
else
    System.out.println("You are NOT young");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not formulated quite well, but from what I can see you are trying to initialize int value with the method that returns String.

```
int age = ageTxt.getText( );
```

Instead, you should do:

```
String ageS = ageTxt.getText();
int age = Integer.parseInt(ageS);
if (age < 30) {
  // do something
}
```

And of course make sure parseInt doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Hope so this will help you, as you are not casting the it to integer, getText() return a string that is why it gives you exception. First convert it into int like this and then use it.

```
JTextField ageTxt;
ageTxt = new JTextField("30");
int age = Integer.parseInt(ageTxt.getText( ));

if (age < 30){
    System.out.println("You are young");
}
else{
    System.out.println("You are NOT young");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ageTxt.getText()` returns a `String` object containing the characters typed by the user, and you try to put it in a `int` var, which can only contain integers. So it can't work. Just put it in a String object, then parse it to get the integer value by doing `Integer.parseInt(myStringObject)`. Be careful this can throw an exception if the String object doesn't contains an integer number.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a scanner instead of having a jtextfield. here is the code i made :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[]args){
int age;
Scanner getage = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How old are you");
age = getage.nextInt();
if (age < 30){
System.out.println("You are young");
}
else{
System.out.println("You are NOT young");
}


}
}
```